# Kendo Dropdownlist Cascading: Nothing showing up in child dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am attempting to manually control a cascading kendo dropdownlist. I bind a 'cascade' event to the parent, and when that triggers, go to my server to get the values of the child dropdownlist that are associated with the parent dropdownlist value, and try to update the child dataSource:

`childDropDown.setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: resultArr.fieldValues
 }));`

This does set the dataSource of the child, but nothing shows up in the child dropdownlist.

My dropdownlists are defined as input elements, where the dataSource of the parent is set up with the mvvm method of `data-source="[\'option1\',\'option2\',\'option3\']"` in the input element (building them dynamically, so construct these as strings and add them to a template).

I believe the issue is because there is no cascadeFromField since my dataSource consists of just the option strings, and not objects, but don't know how to fix that when I am dynamically constructing the HTML, so have to set the dataSource in the dropdownlist element string.

Is it possible to utilize Kendo cascading dropdownlists where I change the child options manually on each parent change like I am attempting to do?

Comment: Can you not just do a call .on('change') to retrieve the list you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach a [change](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change) event to the main dropdown, so when it changes, it will reload the sub dropdown's dataSource. Here is an example, where `SourceID` is the main dropdown, and `SubSourceID` is the sub dropdown:

```
function OnChangeSourceID() {
    var kendoSubSourceID = $('#SubSourceID').data('kendoDropDownList');
    var sourceID = $('#SourceID').data('kendoDropDownList').value();

    kendoSubSourceID.setDataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: requestURL + '&source=' + sourceID,

            },
            parameterMap: function(data) {
                return kendo.stringify(data);

            },

        },
        schema: {
            data: 'data',
            total: 'total',

        },

    });

}
```

If you have any question, feel free to ask. I hope, i could be of any help.